# How can I force camera to be black and white on pc?

Tags: windows, camera

I want to do a zoom call but I would like to change the appearance on recording to black and white so that it appears like the computer has a black and white camera built in. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unless Zoom has this as an option, or your camera’s third-party software has an option, that applies this effect it won’t be possible

Comment: I ca 't have something like a middleware before the camera?

Comment: Yes; That would be the third-party software; But if the option doesn’t exist it can’t be applied.

Comment: I've never actually tried it, but streaming software might let you do this. OBS along with OBS Virtual Camera and some filters in OBS might do what you want

Comment: But I want it to affect all the camera apps at once like its part of the drivers

Comment: You would use OBS to capture your camera, then apply filters, and then output to the virtual camera. After that you simply point whatever tools you want at the virtual camera. That way every program "just works".